# How to get count of for loop and store it into dictionary which is inside for loop

Tags: python, django, data-structures

I am trying to get count of for loop inside each if condition if condition is satisfied it should get the count and store it in a dictionary with diffrent keys example code is given below but it gives me diffrent output not what i want

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = preshift.objects.filter(active=True,is_published=True,date_published=self.request.GET.get('date')).values()
        data = {}
        print('/////queryset_count///',queryset.count())
        pre_shift_count = 0
        for i in queryset:
            dt = i['date_published_local'].strftime("%H")
            if int(dt) in range(0,2):
                pre_shift_count+=1
                print('///1////',pre_shift_count)
                data["zero-2"]= pre_shift_count
            else:
                data["zero-2"] = 0

            if int(dt) in range(2,4):
                pre_shift_count+=1
                print('///2////',pre_shift_count)
                data["two-4"] = pre_shift_count
            else:
                data["two-4"] = 0

            if int(dt) in range(4,6):
                pre_shift_count+=1
                print('///3////',pre_shift_count)
                data["two-5"] = pre_shift_count
            else:
                data["two-5"] = 0
    
        return Response({"preshift":data})
```

it gives me output like this

```
    ('/////queryset_count///',4)
    (////1//,1)
    (////3//,0)
    (////3//,1)
    (////3//,2)
    (////3//,3)
    (////3//,4)
    (////3//,5)
```

i have four records but it's printing 5 i don't have idea of how to get perfect count of for loop inside condition
and i want to store data in dictionary like this

```
{
    "preshift":{
        "zero-2":1,
        "two-4":0,
        "two-5":4,
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you print out `i` and `dt` on each iteration to get some more information about what is happening.

Comment: Hello @Code-Apprentice Yes I will do that but can you help me for how to store data in dictionary inside for loop

Comment: What do you need help with exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't have idea of how to get perfect count of for loop inside condition

To get the perfect count of the for loop, I recommend using `enumerate()` built-in function within `Python`.Example:

```
>>> for count, value in enumerate(values):
...     print(count, value)
...
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

This will allow you to keep a perfect count at all times. You can start at count 0 or use +1 to start from 1.

Your desired dictionary is a dictionary within the dictionary. To do this create another dictionary (call b) and use this to assign the values within the forloop. Once all the values are assigned use the other dictionary (call a) and set the key value of `preshift` in a to b, e.g. a["preshift"] = b. This will make it the way you want.

I am also confused on how you are using the variable `pre_shift_count` in this case. An easy way around this is to use the `b` dictionary of type int. You would initialize with `defaultdict(int)` in `python` and then in each case increment the value by 1 e.g., `b[key]+=1`

Comment: Hello @AzyCrw4282 i have tried `defaultdict(int)` it worked well but in final output it gives me datatype of  dict and  value like this `defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'data2': 6, 'data1': 3})` how to remove that data type and get only data

Comment: It seems like this is printing the object, there should be methods associated with this object that will give what you want. Try objname.<method> and select the correct one. I am slightly busy go look into it atm.

Comment: also try this, wrap it with dict(), e. g., print(dict(object))